# The problems is "Objective-c exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException reason Width]: unrecognized sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift

I have problems in use

```
var a = new MDDatePickerDialog()
```

The problems is:

> "Objective-c exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException reason Width]: unrecognized sent to instance"

Comment: `MDDatePickerDialog` comes from ?

Comment: Is that supposed to be Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: Looks like the Library is Obj-C https://github.com/fpt-software/Material-Controls-For-iOS and he tries to call it from Swift. Did you @kushal maybe missed the Bridging header?